# How to count JSON Objects in array filtered by attribute of the object by JSONPath

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm writing a JSONPath expression that counts objects in an array while filtering by one of the field of the object.

Input JSON taken from http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

And my expression that extracts object where "category" is "fiction".

```
$.store.book[?(@.category == "fiction")]
```

The output is as expected.

```
[
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "Evelyn Waugh",
      "title" : "Sword of Honour",
      "price" : 12.99
   },
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "Herman Melville",
      "title" : "Moby Dick",
      "isbn" : "0-553-21311-3",
      "price" : 8.99
   },
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "J. R. R. Tolkien",
      "title" : "The Lord of the Rings",
      "isbn" : "0-395-19395-8",
      "price" : 22.99
   }
]
```

So far so good.  What I would like to achieve is to count the number of objects in the array.  In this case 3.  I tried this expression:

```
$.store.book[?(@.category == "fiction")].length()
```

The output is not what I expected.

```
[
   4,
   5,
   5
]
```

The below didn't work either

```
$.store[?(@.book[*].category == "fiction")].length()
```

How do I count the number of elements in the array?   If I use `jq` it could be written as

```
[.store.book[] | select (.category == "fiction")] | length
```

Comment: Looks like I have to wrap the resulting object in another JsonPath , and apply the length().  JsonPath appears to be pretty weak

Comment: This is a weird thing that always seemed as a result of wrong design concept to me. Quite annoying.

Comment: Indeed the API seems to have some design flaw.  I started looking into [jq for Java](https://github.com/bskaggs/jjq).  It's a JNA wrapper for libjq.  If I can make it work with Jackson JSON object, I will switch to jjq

Comment: What if you just filter the nodes and evaluate the expression to `JSONArray` so that just take it length? It does not seem to be very declarative, but it does not require "heavy weapons" like what JNA is.

Comment: I ditched the JsonPath.  I've been using [jackson-jq](https://github.com/eiiches/jackson-jq).  It's mostly compatible with jq.  `jjq` is still a viable option if you need the genuine jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very late for the answer but I came across this scenario recently and managed to get the number of object inside the array using below JsonPath query as per the JSON provided in question:

```
$.length($.store.book[?(@.category == "fiction")].length())
```